# How to set the exact boundaries of a ggplot2 plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made the following plot using coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1,20)) but as you can see, the x-axis extends past the 20 mark. I'd like to know how to set the exact point at which the plot will end.

Plot:

[image]

Comment: In `coord_cartesian` set `expand=FALSE`.

Comment: Much appreciated. Sorry for my failure to properly RTFM!